# How to add an object to HttpContext.Current so it is available later on in processing?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to add value to `HttpContext.Current` inside of controller action so it is later available without need of passing it directly to a method. How can I do it?
I have action method:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Method([FromBody] MyRequestDto myRequest )
```

I want to add `myRequest` to`HttpContext.Current` so I can read it in the method that is not invoked from `Method`.

Answer (score 2):

You can store almost anything you like in the [`HttpContext.Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.items?view=netframework-4.8) property.

For example:

```
var myThing = new Foo();
HttpContext.Items.Add("myFoo", myThing);
```

And later:

```
var myThing = HttpContext.Items["myFoo"];
```

Also note that in ASP.NET Core, `HttpContext.Current` isn't valid code anymore. You can access the context in a controller using `this.HttpContext` or elsewhere with dependency injection using the `IHttpContextAccessor` interface.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core `HttpContext.Current` was removed. Inside the controller you can use [`ControllerBase.HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property and add to it's [`Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.items?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property some value:

> `HttpContext.Items` - Gets or sets a key/value collection that can be used to share data within the scope of this request.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Method([FromBody] MyRequestDto myRequest)
{
    HttpContext.Items["test"] = myRequest;
}
```